# How to call variable inside document.getElementById('c1').innerHTML in an Ionic app

Tags: javascript, angular, ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3

I am calling html,css data using the below line of code on my html from my `home.ts` file

```
document.getElementById('c1').innerHTML = '<ol><li>html data</li></ol>';
```

But what I want to achieve is to call `this.a` where `html data` is written, how do I do this?

Answer (score 1):

This how you can do this:

```
document.getElementById('c1').innerHTML = `<ol><li>`+this.a+`</li></ol>`;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [String Interpolation](https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/docs/template-strings.html) to concatenate `this.a` and this way your code it's cleaner and more readable:

```
document.getElementById('c1').innerHTML = `<ol><li>${ this.a }</li></ol>`;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<div id="c1" [innerHTML]="theHtmlString"></div>
```

in your typescript

```
this.theHtmlString = `<ol><li>${this.a}</li></ol>`
```